# Drawing a line between two points using chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

How do I draw a line between point (3,3) and point (1,1) in the attached picture.

This is a chart control. WinForms application using c#

[image: Chart example]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //chart1 is the name of the chart control
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add("Area");
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY.Maximum = 10;
    chart1.ChartAreas["Area"].AxisY.Interval = 1;


    chart1.Series.Add("Node");
    chart1.Series.Add("DG");
    chart1.Series["Node"].Color = Color.Blue;
    chart1.Series["DG"].Color = Color.Red;


    chart1.Series["Node"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
    chart1.Series["Node"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(8, 2));
    chart1.Series["DG"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 3));

    chart1.Series["Node"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
    chart1.Series["DG"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Point;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's the type of the Chart control that you're using ?

Comment: K good question Russ. I am using the default chart control that comes with Visual Studio 2012. Version4.5 Microsoft component.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this should do it;

```
        chart1.Series.Add("Line");
        chart1.Series["Line"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 1));
        chart1.Series["Line"].Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 3));
        chart1.Series["Line"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Comment: freaking awesome. Did u get this from a book! I cant find documentation on this kinda stuff!

Comment: @jvelez I just played around with intellisense

Comment: I see! the key is to know that a series can be a line or a bar chart. Then you add it to the current chart! Thank you for the help I was stuck with this.

Comment: @jvelez, it seem, I never looked at the chart usercontrol before now

Answer (score 0):

This version of Fredou's answer worked for me:

```
chart1.Series.Add("Line");
chart1.Series["Line"].Points.AddXY( x, y);
chart1.Series["Line"].Points.AddXY( x, y);
chart1.Series["Line"].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
```